# the meaning of 'with profit' here

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Lawson had the pedagogic instinct; whenever he found anything out he
>   was eager to impart it; and because he taught with delight **he talked
>   with profit**. Philip, without thinking anything about it, had got into
>   the habit of sitting by his side.
>
> *Of Human Bondage by W. Somerset Maugham*

Does the '**profit**' here mean '**advantage**'? If so, whose advantage does this sentence mean? talker or listener?

Comment: From the quoted snippet, one would conclude that he profited by his teaching.   Just as it was his delight, it was his profit.

Comment: Lawson is a good teacher and eager to share his knowledge. When you listen to him, you learn something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maugham is echoing a very famous line from the *Art of Poetry* by the Roman poet Horace, which every educated reader of Maugham's generation would recognize. Here's Ben Jonson's translation (1640):

> Poets would either profit or delight,
>   Or mixing sweet and fit, teach life the right.

In applying the tag to a teacher, Maugham cleverly twists its sense: because Larson delights in teaching, his teaching is profitable to those whom he teaches.